# Getting last element of the strings in a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B, 
  'a', '304 49494 3033 23', 
  'b', '958 49494 5859',
  'c', '304 4535 59',
)
```

I now want to create a new column that shows the last element of B. Here is the desired output:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~C, 
  'a', '23', 
  'b', '5859',
  'c', '59',
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove everything until last whitespace to get last element.

```
df$C <- sub('.*\\s', '', df$B)
```

Put this in `mutate` for `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(C = sub('.*\\s', '', B))

#   A     B                 C    
#  <chr> <chr>             <chr>
#1 a     304 49494 3033 23 23   
#2 b     958 49494 5859    5859 
#3 c     304 4535 59       59
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I definitely like the second option with the dplyr. Do you know any documentation that I can find the string manipulation with dplyr? @Ronak Shah

Comment: There are lot of functions in `stringr` package for string manipulation which you can use along with `dplyr`.